# JSONLoader not displaying model

Tags: json, three.js

So I've taken a class in Three.js only to find out I haven't been educated in how to load models.  I found a model on Turbosquid.com `<http://storage2.turbosquid.com/Download/index.php?ID=717563_8377529>`, and successfully converted it to JSON using convert_obj_three.py.

I've surfed for good code and found a few decent examples on stackoverflow, but for some reason when I run it in chrome, I get no model.

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script>

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        var geometry;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});

        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

        loader.load( "LeePerrySmith.js", function( geometry ) {

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
            mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
            mesh.position.y = 0;
            mesh.position.x = 0;
            mesh.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
            scene.add( mesh );
            mesh.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            alert("hit");

            } );


        camera.position.z = 5;

        var render = function () {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();

    </script>
</body>
```

I am storing both the HTML file and the e100.js model file in the same directory.  Is there some pathing that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I've tested your code here with a simple cube I exported as a js file and it works fine. Initially I'd suspect 3 things:

1) Perhaps the mesh is super tiny and your not able to see it, try a `mesh.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );` see if that changes anything. **OR** reduce your camera's z position to "move in" a bit.

2) The pathing looks fine, you could use a relative path like "./e100.js" if you wanted to be extra sure, but it really isn't necessary.

3) Maybe the mesh has inverted normals, or some other flaw. Just for testing you could try setting your mesh to render a texture on both sides to see if that's the issue like so:

```
mesh.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

**OR** you could try a more rudimentary material like `MeshBasicMaterial` in lieu or your Normal version and see if that helps.

Keep your console open while the model is loading, look for any errors as it does. If none of this works I'd suspect the model, but that's jumping the gun at this point.

Happy hunting,

Edit: cube.js

```
{
"metadata" :
{
"formatVersion" : 3.1,
"generatedBy" : "Blender 2.66 Exporter",
"vertices" : 8,
"faces" : 6,
"normals" : 8,
"colors" : 0,
"uvs" : [24],
"materials" : 1,
"morphTargets" : 0,
"bones" : 0
},
"scale" : 1.000000,
"materials" : [ {
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "Material",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "cube.png",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Phong",
        "specularCoef" : 50,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    }],
"vertices" : [1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1],
"morphTargets" : [],
"normals" : [0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349],
"colors" : [],
"uvs" : [[0.33408,0.333114,0.334191,0.659296,0.009852,0.659305,0.009721,0.333137,0.991035,0.334072,0.663423,0.334025,0.663036,0.005624,0.991002,0.005943,0.991246,0.333487,0.991261,0.6585,0.663173,0.658447,0.662825,0.334005,0.662568,0.33421,0.662689,0.65851,0.335127,0.658476,0.335112,0.333952,0.335825,0.007042,0.335835,0.333228,0.008133,0.333306,0.008138,0.006861,0.335761,0.333299,0.335071,0.005883,0.663081,0.006277,0.663095,0.333865]],
"faces" : [43,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,43,4,7,6,5,0,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,43,0,4,5,1,0,8,9,10,11,0,4,7,1,43,1,5,6,2,0,12,13,14,15,1,7,6,2,43,2,6,7,3,0,16,17,18,19,2,6,5,3,43,4,0,3,7,0,20,21,22,23,4,0,3,5],
"bones" : [],
"skinIndices" : [],
"skinWeights" : [],
"animation" : {}
}
```

Comment: Well I tried all four suggestions and I still don't have any idea what's wrong.  I'm working the code in Notepad++, and all that I can identify is that the GET is throwing an error on my `src="three.min.js"` call and that subsequently THREE is not defined.  Should I be using the .prototype?

Comment: So I managed to get the code to run uninhibited in the console, but still, no result.

Comment: That is unfortunate, have you tried another model file? I'll edit my answer to have a simple cube.js file's contents, perhaps the model file is the culprit?

Comment: I tried using the `LeePerry.js` file from the Three.js master file, as recommended by Mrdoob in another post.  So apparently it's not the model.

Comment: Yikes, this one is tricky. So the code you put up works fine, the model has been eliminated, is there any other quirk with your setup that might be the culprit? Bad video driver (do the Three.js examples work?) What about the `"three.min.js"` file reference, can you try this instead `"https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"` and see if that helps?

Comment: I've done all that.  I really should put up new code, but I can't see how.  I cleaned it up a bit and deleted the animation since the console didn't like that.  The samples display fine.  The code looks clean in the console and the calls in the network tab are all successful or show a 200 (the three.js src call).  I really am stymied.  I'm running locally, so I had to follow the instructions for that as shown in the wiki, but there don't seem to be any other factors that I'm missing.

Comment: I got it.  It was a white model on a white background.  Best to start out with a MeshPhongMaterial and a light source.