# Three.js JSON runtime changing material (texture)

Tags: three.js

I have json exported from Blender. How to change textures for some materials of json models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day, once a model and subsequent textures are loaded they become THREE.Mesh and THREE.Material bound textures. So the loading, while an important clue, isn't neccessarily a factor. To change a texture at runtime you catch the mesh post loading event

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(), function (geometry) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
};
```

Then later or even within the loader above you can apply a custom texture like so:

```
mesh.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'newTexture.png' );
```

or if you have a multiple material Mesh via THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials) you need to determine the index of the texture you wish to swap out and use this pattern:

```
mesh.material.materials[index].map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'newTexture.png' );
```

Now there are a number of related posts, not neccessarily regarding JSON. But you can use these as references as well [Loading Maya model with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607171/loading-maya-model-with-three-js/18623706#18623706) and [JSONLoader not displaying model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445119/jsonloader-not-displaying-model/18453854#18453854)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#materialchange').on('click',function(){
  oparcie.material.materials[0].map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('inne.png');
});
```

This worked just fine ;)
It DOES look like unusually nested path though